# Spring Boot 3.0.0+ with JAVA class DTO

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, dto

[image]

I am doing some testing in order to get a design idea. Through a request with JSON I want to create a DTO class within a GET

```
package org.crea.w4ag_mock.mocker;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import org.crea.w4ag_mock.enums.TimeFramesEnum;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class ParamsDTO {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private TimeFramesEnum timeFramesEnum;
    private double randNum;
}
```

where (I'm also trying to figure out how to have Enun lowercase):

```
package org.crea.w4ag_mock.enums;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public enum TimeFramesEnum {

    /*
    baseline = BASELINE
    period2_2040 = PERIOD2_2040
    period3_2070 = PERIOD2_2070
    */

    BASELINE,
    PERIOD2_2040,
    PERIOD2_2070
}
```

I have my class Application (@SpringBootApplication) + Controller (@RestController):

```
package org.crea.w4ag_mock;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.crea.w4ag_mock.mocker.*;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Water4AgriFoodMockerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Water4AgriFoodMockerApplication.class, args);

    }

    @GetMapping("mock")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<ParamsDTO> getMock(@RequestParam(value = "pars") String parametersDTO) throws IOException {
        final ParamsDTO paramsDTO =
                new ObjectMapper()
                        .readValue(parametersDTO, ParamsDTO.class);

        paramsDTO.setRandNum(12345);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(paramsDTO);
    }

}
```

I convert my JSON to a URL-encoded JSON (https://onlinejsontools.com/url-encode-json). **Note, this is because TOMCAT reports me an error with a plain JSON**:

```
{
"id":"1",
"name":"test",
"timeFramesEnum":"BASELINE"
}
```

And I use POSTMAN to test the whole thing:

[image]

So far so good, but if I create a proper Controller class I get the following error message in Postman:

```
package org.crea.w4ag_mock.controller;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.crea.w4ag_mock.mocker.*;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="api/v1/")
public class Water4AgriFoodMockController {

    @GetMapping("mock1")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<ParamsDTO> getMock1(@RequestParam(value = "pars") String parametersDTO) throws IOException {
        final ParamsDTO paramsDTO =
                new ObjectMapper()
                        .readValue(parametersDTO, ParamsDTO.class);

        paramsDTO.setRandNum(12345);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(paramsDTO);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are still calling `/mock` in Postman. Seems like your controller listens to `/mock1`.

Comment: changed. Was a typo, sorry. I have updated the image (I still have the error)

Comment: How does `Water4AgriFoodMockerApplication` look after you made the separate controller?

Comment: I think your mapping should start with `/`.

Try ``@RequestMapping(path="/api/v1/")``

also ``@GetMapping("/mock1")``

Comment: Hi, Water4AgriFoodMockerApplication is just a simple "SpringBootApplication". I added "RestController" just to do some testing since the appropriate "RestController" class was not working

Comment: @Pioter88 I added your suggestion "/api/v1/", but still the 404 error on: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/mock1?pars=%7B%0A%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%0A%22name%22%3A%22test%22%2C%0A%22timeFramesEnum%22%3A%22BASELINE%22%0A%7D

Comment: @Pioter88 I added your suggetion (2), i.e., @GetMapping("/mock1") but I still have the 404 error

Comment: That is strange.... Please make sure your mappings look like this:  
  
``@RequestMapping("/api/v1")``  
``@GetMapping("/mock1")``  
  
All mappings should start with `/` but not ending with `/`. In previous comment it was my fault because you had ``v1/`` and ``/mock1`` resulting ``v1//mock1``

Comment: @Pioter88 fixed in `@RequestMapping(path="/api/v1")` and "`GetMapping("/mock1")` in Controller class, but I still have 404 error (double check)

Comment: I use this type of things and my Controllers are annotated like this: ´´@RestController
@RequestMapping("/mainPath")
public class MyController´´ and the restpoint: ´´@GetMapping(value = "mypath", produces = WSConstants.JSON_MEDIATYPE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity myGetMethod(@RequestParam("persid") String persid)´´

Comment: The error can also be caused by the component scan not finding your rest-controller class. The component scan is triggered by the `@SpringBootApplication`-annotation on your application class, and (by default) your controller-class has to be in the same package or a sub-package of the application class for it to be found.

Comment: @marstran I added a new figure in the question about  package or a sub-package

Comment: And you are sure that your application-class still has the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation?

Comment: At this point it looks like its related to Spring not finding controller. Your packages are ok, one last tip comming to my mind is Maven. I had numerous issues caused by it. Please try  Maven -> lifecycle -> clean or validate. You can find Maven tab on the right in InteliJ.

Comment: @marstran yes. My class has SpringBootApplication as you can see from the code example